# Computing series containing extremely large values of Binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, computational-mathematics

This might not be the right forum for this question but here goes:
In order to estimate the run-time, I need to compute the cumulative probability of getting all combinations in a certain simulation. The formula for the probability is

$$ P_n(m) = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k} \left( \frac{k}{n} \right)^m = 1+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} \left( 1 - \frac{k}{n} \right)^m $$

My program is running in Visual Basic using Excel but every time I use a value for n above the order of 1500 (and m up to an order of 10 to 100 times higher) I get overflow. Stirling does not really work (I think) because of the series expression. So is there some other trick that might work (except for manual programming and finding the exponents and putting everything together in strings) or is there some way to get a good approximation to the series expression - maybe like some integral?

Comment: So what size is $m$ compared to $n$?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to some. You should know this and how to use MathJax by now, you've been a member for over a year.

Comment: And please use MathJax: it took me what, two minutes to edit that in for you?

Comment: m is usually at least a magnitude greater than n

Answer (score 1):

For slightly more convenience in the case $m=0$, let your summation start at $k=0$ instead of $1$.  Then
$$P_n(m) = \frac{n!}{n^m}\left\{ {m \atop n} \right\}$$
where $\left\{ {m \atop n} \right\}$ is a [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

The Stirling numbers can be computed using the recursion

$$ \left\{ {m+1 \atop n} \right\} = n \left\{ {m \atop n} \right\} 
+ \left\{ {m \atop n-1} \right\} $$

which corresponds to this recursion for $P_n(m)$:

$$ P_n(m+1) = P_n(m) + \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^m P_{n-1}(m) $$
with boundary conditions $P_{n}(0) = 1$ for $n \ge 1$, 
$P_n(m) = 0$ for $n > m$. I don't think this should result in any overflows, and it lets you compute all $P_n(m)$ for $1 \le n \le N$, $1 \le m \le M$ in time and space $\mathcal O(MN)$.

Comment: Robert Israel: Thanks, but I already knew the recurrence relation (see my 2.nd answer to the question "Expected length of conditional random sequence of n integers") and a bit later I learned from Wolfram Alpha about the relationship with Stirling 2. However, as explained in my next comment, I am afraid using the recurrence relation would take even longer than just increasing my simulation time directly.

Comment: I am generating a table seating sequence according to certain criteria. I only generate valid sequences at random but get exceedingly many dublets, which I later eliminate with Quicksort. 
With 11 people I get n = 312474 non-dublets out of 12 mill generated in 5 hrs 56 minutes, mean(m) = 4.13 mill, sigma(m)=4.15 mill and mean + 2xsigma = 12.43 mill but I can not compute the confidence level and your suggestion that I use the recurrence relation would take almost 4E12 cyclings, which would take ages compared to just doubling my runs.  So what I really need is an approximation formula.